# Which of these operations are better in terms of memory savings and CPU? (Java)

Tags: java, loops, memory, assembly, cpu

I am programming in an environment where memory is limited. So I would like to know which is the best option, and why. Does it make a significant difference?
Not sure how Java handles Assembly...

**Option A?** The if check is done each for loop

```
private static boolean checkState(int[][] matrix, int option){
    for (int X=0; X < 5; X++)
        for (int Y=0; Y < 5; Y++)
            if (option == 0){ //if option is 0, checks if empty (-1 on all fields means empty in this case)
                if (matrix[Y][X] != -1)
                    return false;
            } else //if option is 1, checks if full (if at least one camp has -1, it means it's not full)
                if (matrix[Y][X] == -1) 
                    return false;

    return true;
}
```

**Option B?** The if statement is done before the for loop, but there are two (almost identical) versions of the for loop

```
private static boolean checkState(int[][] matrix, int option){
    if (option == 0) {
        for (int X=0; X < 5; X++)
            for (int Y=0; Y < 5; Y++)
                if (matrix[Y][X] != -1)
                    return false;
    } else
        for (int X=0; X < 5; X++)
            for (int Y=0; Y < 5; Y++)
                if (matrix[Y][X] == -1)
                    return false;
    return true;
}
```

**Pption C?** Two distinct functions

```
private static boolean checkEmpty(int[][] matrix){
    for (int X=0; X < 5; X++)
                for (int Y=0; Y < 5; Y++)
                    if (matrix[Y][X] != -1)
                        return false;
    return true;
}

private static boolean checkFull(int[][] matrix){
    for (int X=0; X < 5; X++)
                for (int Y=0; Y < 5; Y++)
                    if (matrix[Y][X] != -1)
                        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Although option B looks like it could perform better than option A, this is all about branch prediction which is handled inside the CPU. In fact, I would be surprised if you ever saw any performance difference. This means, you should not optimize your code to get better performance. _You should always optimize your code to get better readability._ Option C (which has a little copy and paste mistake, btw) is on a good way.

Comment: "Always" is such a big word. :)

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Yes, and "always" true. :-) Seriously, I tend to use such big words to explain beginners that they should go one direction only and not think of anything else besides it. Once getting used to some good or best practice, one can consider doing its work in another way. The difference is knowledge and experience.

Answer (score 0):

I think Option B would be better because the if condition would be checked only once, if its true the code in if block will be executed otherwise the code in the else block will get executed

Option A clearly is a bad option as the if block gets executed for every iteration of the loop.

Option C seems an overkill, there's no need to create separate methods for this thing.

Comment: Yes, but in option B, a big chunk of code is repeated

Comment: yup it seems, but the repeated code does not gets executed. A few extra lines don't hurt if it improves your execution time :)

Answer (score 0):

none of thew above would make any sizable difference in performance. Technically option C is better. A defined directed method that does a single task assigned to it is better for performance as well as readability. But for a 5x5 matrix depth you wont see any major deviations between the 3 approaches. Also your examples have no impact on memory consumption but CPU....yes may be.  but then again for a 5x5 matrix the program would finish before you could blink so i don't think its gonna matter much.